# How to dynamically Add / Remove pages in laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm totally new in Laravel.
I'm just trying to create a website where I want to add and remove pages dynamically and also want to add slug in **route** dynamically.

this is what my database tables looks like

## Pages

```
 id         
 title              
 body       
 image  
 slug
```

how can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a dedicated controller
`php artisan make:controller PageController`

then you need a route to do that for instance in your `routes/web.php` file
`Route::get('pages/{slug}', 'PageController@show');`

then in you `PageController` create a `show` method which will take the given slug

```php
class PageController extends Controller
{
    public function show($slug)
    {
        $page = Page::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();
        
        return view('pages.show', ['page' => $page]);
    }
}
```

to create slug dynamically on creation in your `Page.php` model define a [MUTATOR](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator)

```php
class Page extends Model
{
    /**
     * Set slug before storing the page into database.
     *
     * @param $value
     */
    public function setTitleAttribute($value): void
    {
        $this->attributes['slug'] = \Illuminate\Support\Str::slug($value);
        $this->attributes['title'] = $value;
    }
}
```

and finally to create link to your pages make an anchor tag like below

```html
<a href="/pages/YOUR-PAGE-SLUG-TITLE">My cool link</a>
```

**SIDE NOTE**
With creating a MUTATOR you don't need to set slug on creating the page
for example

```php
Page::create([
    'title' => 'foobar',
    'body'  => 'foobar',
    'image' => 'foobar',
     // 'slug'  => 'foobar', YOU DO NOT NEED TO SET SLUG EVER.
]);
```